# Can see response only when using the e.preventDefault() is used

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

As the question suggests, I am able to see the response only when I use e.preventDefault(). If I comment out the the e.prevendefault and dump the request then the response is empty or null.

Here's a screenshot when using e.preventDefault():
[image: Using e.preventDefault()]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg mt-3">
            <form id="formTUI" action="/designlab" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div id="outerDiv">
                    <div id="tui-image-editor-container" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" name="image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit" id="saveImage">Submit</button>
            </form>
</div>
```

Here's the AJAX code:

```js
 $('#saveImage').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

                // var image64 = imageEditor.toDataURL();
                var image64 = "Hello World"
                console.log(image64);

                jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '/designlab',
                    type: 'POST',
                    // processData: false,
                    // contentType: false,
                    // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                    data: { image:image64 },
                    success: function(response) {
                    // Handle the server response
                    console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle the error
                    console.error(error);
                }
});
```

Here's the Laravel code:

```
public function designPost(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $data = $request->all();
        $image = $request->image;
        return response([$image]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dump($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Note:**
I am not using any form to submit the ajax request, instead passing a payload.
I have also tried to use:

```
$image = $request->image;
AND
$image = $request->input('image');
```

Comment: If indeed it is a submit image, use the submit event instead AND keep the preventDefault

Comment: When you add the preventDefault, it prevents the form from submitting by itself. Without it, the form submits, but the form itself doesn't have the expected `image` input that you add into your ajax call. You have a `div` named `image`, but a `div` is not an `input` and doesn't get passed in the form.

Comment: You're probably right, the issue is I am using TUI image editor, to get the image i have to use imageEditor.toDataURL(). Just for the sake of simplicity I put the 'Hello World' in image64 instead of the data url.

Comment: Please share the RENDERED HTML

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `#saveImage` is a submit button so you just submit the form and your success callback isn't executed because the context is reloaded (the whole page?). When you prevent the submission with `e.preventDefault()` everything is ok. We need your HTML.
Meanwhile try to add to your button `type="button"`:

```
<button id="saveImage" type="button"><img src="submit.jpg" alt="Save" /></button>
```

Otherwise you should use `e.preventDefault()` either here or in the form's submit event handler.
Also the problem is in the future you could for example add an additional field like a caption and the form could be submitted with the ENTER key in this text field. So moving your code into the form's `submit` event's handler could be a future-proof move.

Comment: @mplungjan what sense in the editing? i guess <img> doesn't have `source` attribute

Comment: I have edited the question and added the HTML. Actually I am using TUI Image Editor for some image editing.

Comment: Apologies for the source. Made more sense to have an image in there